# Jade, Express.js, NodeJS - Automatically rendering the UI with new data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

The JSON Object (stories) looks like this:

```
    [ {
            title: "Story of Learning NodeJS",
            id: "1",
            description: "Interesting, Fun, Exciting" 
    }]
```

The JADE template to render the stories looks like this:

```
 ul
    each story in stories
        li
            span#storyTitle= story.title
```

This will render the list of stories in the client side. Now, I have a Create Story functionality, using which I will add a new story, hence adding it to the JSON object. I want this to be reflected in the Client UI without refreshing the page.

I tried using the:

```
response.render("index", {stories: stories });
```

after the POST method adds the story to the stories object. But the rendering does not happen.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several possiblities:

**Using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/):**

There is a good feature you can use, it is called [Live HTML Templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtmltemplates). You can easily bind your data and when on the backend they change, it also changes in frontend. But you'd need to rewrite your app :(

**Using jQuery:**
This is a small script that uses `$.load` to reload a part of the paga:

```
$.reloadSection = function (id) {
  var q = window.location.pathname + (window.location.search || "") + " " + id;
  $(id).load(q, function () {});
};
```

Now :

```
$.reloadSection('#my-id');
```

It works!

Comment: Awesome.. reloadSection worked like a charm.. Thank you @Vinz243. I will also explore about the possibility of using Meteor framework. :)